# Seesmic Twitter image upload problem

Tags: photos, twitter, seesmic

So I started using **Seesmic** application to post on **FaceBook** and **Twitter**, but I have problem when uploading images in Twitter statuses.

If I use **yfrog.com** as service for uploading images in the settings, it uploads ok and adds the link. No problem.

But I don't like using yfrog because official twitter doesn't show the image normally if it isn't uploaded on official Twitter servers...

So I want to use the option Twitter or Twitpic for the image upload, but when I try to sent tweet with image using this settings it fails with this error:

"**Cannot update status**

The service provider cannot be reached. Please retry later."

So I try to Retry later.. but still won't work.

Anyone with same problem or solution? I tried Googling, but nothing helpful. Or is there any small app for twitter + facebook with official twitter image uploading that you would recommend?